# something like delete-frame but that would also delete the last frame -- like alt+f4

Tags: frames

I would like a more handy shortcut to basically the system's `alt-f4` to close the current emacs window. `delete-frame` is not far from that, but it refuses to close the last frame: `Attempt to delete the sole visible or iconified frame`.

How could I get a function that would override that safety? Note that I'm using emacs-client with `emacsclient -c "$@" --alternate-editor= &` and I would like that the server stays running -- with is the behaviour with `alt-f4`.

I'm not interested in OS shortcuts because I'm using `spacemacs` and I can get better shortcuts, like `SPC o F` for instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think @harpo answered the question adequately in a comment.  Here's some additional info, in case it helps.

You can bind a key to a command that deletes the frame, and if error "*Attempt...*" is raised then kill Emacs instead. For that, use `condition-case` to handle the error.  That way you can use a single key to either delete a frame or, if it is the last one, kill Emacs.

For example:

```el
(defun delete-frame-or-kill-emacs ()
  "Delete the selected frame.  If the last one, kill Emacs."
  (interactive)
  (condition-case nil (delete-frame) (error (kill-emacs))))

(global-set-key [remap delete-frame] 'delete-frame-or-kill-emacs)
```

(However, I wouldn't recommend using such a command, as it is too easy to accidentally kill Emacs.)

---

**Update after your comment.**

If you are using emacsserver and emacsclient then try `(save-buffers-kill-terminal)` instead of `(kill-emacs)`. That should delete the frame but keep the server alive. I didn't see that you had specified that you were in such a context.  (`save-buffers-kill-terminal` is bound to `C-x C-c` in a client frame.) See the Emacs manual, node [`emacsclient` Options](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html).

And in that case, `C-x C-c` should be *all* you need - it sounds like it does just what you are asking for. And if you prefer that it be invoked from another key then just bind that key to `save-buffers-kill-terminal`.

Comment: that's pretty close now! however the problem is that that also kills the emacs server... as i said, I would like that the emacs-server keeps running.

Comment: not quite, `save-buffers-kill-terminal` seems to kill two frames if I have two open. so i probably still want the condition, between `delete-frame` and `save-buffers-kill-terminal`. I'll try that now.

Comment: that's it, the condition between `save-buffers-kill-terminal` and `delete-frame` is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you really want is `kill-emacs`. In Windows, it's `Ctrl+F4` that closes the "frame" (in apps that can have multiple windows), and it wouldn't close the app in any case that I can think of. Whereas `Alt+F4` will close all of the child windows regardless (after prompting to save). So actually Emacs is parallel with this.

(Answer moved from comment on question.)

Comment: yes as @Drew pointed out I'd like to kill the whole emacs only if it's the last frame open (and also that emacs-server keeps running)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Spacemacs, I suppose you set `dotspacemacs-persistent-server` to `t`. Then you should be able to kill the current frame with `SPC q z`. Note that I don't use that myself and I cannot verify it right now. There is also some documentation about it there: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/5baa70057b4b2bfebce3ec8918101a252e00c405/doc/DOCUMENTATION.org#keeping-the-server-alive

Comment: it works as I want even with `dotspacemacs-persistent-server` at `nil` :-) But I'll change it to `t` just in case. So, great, i'll try to get used to this one then...